# how to use asan on a long-time-running server program?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, g++, address-sanitizer

I have a long-time-running server program, and I want to use asan to instrument this program for memory leaks.
My solution:

```
CXXFLAGS+="-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize-recover=address"
LDFLAGS+="-lasan"
# start the program
LD_PRELOAD=libasan.so.5 ASAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=false:alloc_dealloc_mismatch=0 ./bin/server > asan_report 2>&1 &
```

But it seems asan only report for once
I want it to report periodically, how to do that ?

Comment: How are you going to distinguish between memory that won't be released in the future and memory that will be released in the future, but hasn't yet been released? At the end of a program, the list of deallocations is final and you can see what went missing. But during a program ASAN can't peer into the future and predict what will happen.

Comment: Your `LDFLAGS` setting is incorrect, it should be `LDFLAGS=-fsanitize=address` (raw `-lasan` might work but is unreliable and it's use is discouraged by Asan developers).

Comment: Instead of `LD_PRELOAD=libasan.so.5` better do a more generic and portable `LD_PRELOAD=$(gcc -print-file-name=libasan.so)`.

Answer (score 2):

Given that your ultimate goal is to understand whether your long running program is experiencing undesirable growth, and if so why, you should consider a solution like https://github.com/vmware/chap that doesn't require instrumenting your program.

Just grab a live core of your program periodically using gcore or something similar, maybe daily at a time when your program isn't under heavy load if your program runs for multiple days.

Open each core with chap and look at the results of the following commands:

```
count leaked
count writable
```

If the *leaked* count is non-zero, your program has the sort of leak where dynamically allocated memory has become unreachable.  In such a case, https://github.com/vmware/chap/blob/master/USERGUIDE.md#analyzing-memory-leaks gives some pointers as to how to figure out what the leaks are.

If the *writable* count is larger than you would expect, or seems to be getting larger each time, you are getting growth for some other reason, such as growth of some sort of std container.  See https://github.com/vmware/chap/blob/master/USERGUIDE.md#analyzing-memory-growth for some thoughts on how to investigate further in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to report periodically

You can call `__lsan_do_recoverable_leak_check();` at an opportune time in your dispatch loop.

From [lsan_interface.h](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/include/sanitizer/lsan_interface.h):

```
  // Check for leaks now. Returns zero if no leaks have been found or if leak
  // detection is disabled, non-zero otherwise.
  // This function may be called repeatedly, e.g. to periodically check a
  // long-running process. It prints a leak report if appropriate, but does not
  // terminate the process. It does not affect the behavior of
  // __lsan_do_leak_check() or the end-of-process leak check, and is not
  // affected by them.
```

This will print the same leaks repeatedly (there is no "print only new leaks since last call" function).

P.S. Since your program is linked with `libasan` already, there is no reason to `LD_PRELOAD` anything, and there are many disadvantages.